# Compile error in JAVA - (<anonymous ListSelectionListener>)

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, listselectionlistener

I have a homework assignment where I am buildign a GUI JPane that holds other JPanes to allow for multiple objects to be displayed. I am getting a compile error on one of my listeners and could use some help figuring this one out. Let me preface all of this by saying that we are not allowed to use an IDE.

The error is:

```
F:\Java\Lab 8\Lab8.java:84: error: cannot find symbol
        jcbo.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            ^
  symbol:   method addListSelectionListener(<anonymous ListSelectionListener>)
  location: variable jcbo of type JComboBox<String>
1 error
```

The project code is:

```
import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;
   import javax.swing.*;
   import javax.swing.event.*;
   import javax.swing.border.*;
   import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.util.EventObject;


   public class Lab8 extends JFrame {

       public String name;
       public String[] ageRanges = {"Select an Age Range","Under 20", "20-29", "30-39", "40-49", "50-59", "60 and Above"};
       public String[] destination = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Moon", "Mars", "Jupiter / Europa", "Saturn / Triton", "Pluto + Sharon"};
        final JTextField txtName = new JTextField(20);
        String value;


       public Lab8()
       {





           // Create an array of Strings for age ranges
           final JComboBox<String> jcbo = new JComboBox<String>(ageRanges);
           jcbo.setForeground(Color.blue);
           jcbo.setBackground(Color.white);


           // Create an array of String destinations




           // Declare radio buttons
           JRadioButton jrbMonday, jrbTuesday, jrbWednesday, jrbThursday, jrbFriday;

           // Create a textfield
           JTextField jMsg = new JTextField(10);


           // Create panel to hold label and textbox.
           JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
           p1.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,0));
           p1.add(new JLabel("Name: "), BorderLayout.WEST);

           p1.add(txtName, BorderLayout.CENTER);
           jMsg.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.LEFT);


           // Create combobox panel.
           JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
           p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,0,5,5));
           p2.add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
           p2.add(new JComboBox<String>(ageRanges), BorderLayout.CENTER);
           p2.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Passenger Name & Age Range"));

            final JList<String> jlst = new JList<String>(destination);

           //Create listbox panel.
           JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
           p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
           p3.add(jlst);
           p3.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Destinations"));



            jlst.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){

                    final int index = jlst.getSelectedIndex();
                    value = destination[index];
                }
            });


            jcbo.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){

                    final int index = jcbo.getSelectedIndex();
                    value = ageRanges[index];
                }
            });




           // Create a print button
           JButton jbtPrint = new JButton("Print");


           // Create a new panel to hold radio buttons.
           JPanel r1 = new JPanel();
           r1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
           r1.add(jrbMonday = new JRadioButton("Monday"));
           r1.add(jrbTuesday = new JRadioButton("Tuesday"));
           r1.add(jrbWednesday = new JRadioButton("Wednesday"));
           r1.add(jrbThursday = new JRadioButton("Thursday"));
           r1.add(jrbFriday = new JRadioButton("Friday"));
           r1.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Departure Days"));
           r1.add(jbtPrint);


           // Create a radio button group to group five buttons
           ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
           group.add(jrbMonday);
           group.add(jrbTuesday);
           group.add(jrbWednesday);
           group.add(jrbThursday);
           group.add(jrbFriday);



           // Create grid to hold contents
           JPanel pMain = new JPanel();
           pMain.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,0));
           add(r1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
           add(p2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
           add(p3, BorderLayout. EAST);



           // Create button listener
           jbtPrint.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

            jrbMonday.addActionListener(new mListener());
            jrbTuesday.addActionListener(new tListener());
            jrbWednesday.addActionListener(new wListener());
            jrbThursday.addActionListener(new rListener());
            jrbFriday.addActionListener(new fListener());



}
            int flag = 0;


            // Declare radio button variable
            boolean monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday;

            public void monday(){
                monday = true;
            }
            public void tuesday(){
                tuesday = true;
            }
            public void wednesday(){
                wednesday = true;
            }
            public void thursday(){
                thursday = true;
            }
            public void friday(){
                friday = true;
            }





            public class mListener implements ActionListener
            {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
              {
              monday();
                flag = 1;
              }
            }

            public class tListener implements ActionListener
                        {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
              {
              tuesday();
                flag = 2;
              }
            }

            public class wListener implements ActionListener
            {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
              {
              wednesday();
                flag = 3;
              }
            }

            public class rListener implements ActionListener
            {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
              {
              thursday();
                flag = 4;
              }
            }

            public class fListener implements ActionListener
            {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
              {
              friday();
              flag = 5;
              }
            }

            public void setText(){
                name = txtName.getText();
        }


           /** Handle the print button */
             class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
                 ButtonListener(){
                 }
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 // Get values from fields
                    setText();
                System.out.println("Passenger's Name: " + name + "\n");
                System.out.println("Age Group: " + ageRanges + "\n");
                System.out.println("Destination: " + value + "\n");
                System.out.println("Departure Day: " + flag  + "\n");



                }
                /*jbtPrint.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {

                    }
                });*/

}





public static void main(String[] args)
       {
           Lab8 frame = new Lab8();
           // frame.pack();
           frame.setTitle("Lab 8 Application");
           frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
           frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           frame.setSize(425, 275);
           frame.setVisible(true);


        }


}
```

Comment: `JComboBox` simply has no method `addListSelectionListener(...)`. It's not a list after all. What are you trying to do? Maybe I guessed it in my answer below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JComboBox` simply has no method `addListSelectionListener(...)`. It's not a list after all.

From your code, it looks like you want some code to trigger when the user selects something in your `JComboBox`. Use an `ActionListener` for that:

```
jcbo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int index = jcbo.getSelectedIndex();
    value = ageRanges[index];
  }
});
```

---

Completely unrelated to the previous:

For the `[Ljava.lang.String;@1283052`, note that calling `toString()` on an array (or concatenating it to an existing string which has the same effect), doesn't give you the contents but a mix of the array type and some internal hash code. For the contents use one of the [`Arrays.toString()` methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html):

```
System.out.println("Age Group: " + Arrays.toString(ageRanges) + "\n");
```

Comment: That almost works, but I get a result of:                          Age Group: [Ljava.lang.String;@1283052

Comment: @Kevin Schultz: That's because you are printing the value of the array `ageRanges`, instead of a single value. Check your code again.

Comment: @Kevin I updated my answer to include outputting the contents of an array. Oh, I think I misunderstood. If you just want to print one value like Tudor assumes, my `Arrays.toString()` advice isn't useful.

Comment: Now the error is:    F:\Java\Lab 8\Lab8.java:243: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.println("Age Group: " + Arrays.toString(ageRanges) + "\n");
                                       ^
  symbol:   variable Arrays
  location: class Lab8.ButtonListener

Comment: The class `Arrays` is in the package `java.util`, import it.

Comment: Phillipp, it compiles just fine now, but it returns the whole array when using the Arrays.toString(ageRanges) in the print line.

Comment: Yes, please read the comments on this answer by Tudor and the one after that by me. You have all the variables you could want to output already, please look at your code.

Comment: Phillipp, My apologies, I misread your answer. I changed the println to a variable to pull just the one ageRange form the array. For some reason it is null regardless of what I select. I have gone back over the code and cannot determine why the value is not returning from the array.

Comment: I feel bad already for doing so much of your homework, but here goes: You never add the `jcbo` combobox to your UI but create a second combobox further below that has no behavior and just displays the age ranges. Also, you assign both the destination and the ageRange the user selects to the same variable `value`. Add the right combobox to your UI, drop the useless one, and use separate variables for what the user selects.

Comment: I had caught the variable error and renamed the other variable but didnt mention it. I found what you pointed out about the second combobox.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

The `JComboBox` class has no `addListSelectionListener` method. See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html).

If you want to intercept the event of changing the current selection try using `addActionListener` instead:

```
jcbo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

         final int index = jcbo.getSelectedIndex();
         value = ageRanges[index];
    }
});
```

Comment: What about addItemListener(ItemListener listener)? Doesn't that handle selection change events?

Answer (score 0):

hmm. if you are not allowed to use an IDE like eclipse, i´ll only give you an direction marker...

check the javadoc of the jcombobox for that method.

you can find it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html